# Processar dados do formulário com javascript e html

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, formulário

Queria fazer um programa que o usuário enviaria 3 notas e após apertar "Calcular", você seria redirecionado pra uma página que apareceria a sua média.
Quem pudesse me ajudar:

```js
 function calcular()
        {
            var ac1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ac1').value, 10);
            var ac2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ac2').value, 10);
            var ac4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ac4').value, 10);              
            var media = ((ac1*2)+(ac2*2)+ac4)/5;
            alert("Sua média desta etapa foi "+media);
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            input {
                margin-left: 100px;
                width: 45px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/teste1pag2" method="get">
                Digite sua nota da Ac1 aqui: <input type="number" id="ac1" min="0" max="10"> <br> 
                Digite sua nota da Ac2 aqui: <input type="number" id="ac2"> <br>
                Digite sua nota de participa&ccedil;&atilde;o aqui: 
                <input type="text" id="ac4" style="margin-left: 49px"> <br>
                <input type="submit" onblur="calcular()" value="Calcular!">
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: opa mano, aprendi já rs

Comment: Aprenda mais fazendo um tour pelo sita https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Quando uma resposta resolver seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Usando somente JavaScript e HTML:

**Script**

```
 function calcular()
        {
            var ac1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ac1').value, 10);
            var ac2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ac2').value, 10);
            var ac4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('ac4').value, 10);              
            var media = ((ac1*2)+(ac2*2)+ac4)/5;
            alert("Sua média desta etapa foi "+media);
            
            window.location.href = "pagina-destino.html?media="+media;
        }
```

**HTM**L - a tag `<form>...</form>` não é necessário para esta solução.

```
Digite sua nota da Ac1 aqui: <input type="number" id="ac1" min="0" max="10"> <br> 
Digite sua nota da Ac2 aqui: <input type="number" id="ac2"> <br>
Digite sua nota de participa&ccedil;&atilde;o aqui: 
<input type="text" id="ac4" style="margin-left: 49px"> <br>
<input type="submit" onclick="calcular()" value="Calcular!">
```

**pagina-destino.html**

```
//Somente funciona para um parametro
//o split separa a string quando encontra o ?
var variaveis=location.search.split("?");
var quebra = variaveis[1].split("=");

//o document.whitein escreve no html o conteudo
document.writeln ("O valor da média é: " + quebra[1]);
```